# No ggplot2 graphs are working: "Error in y[setdiff(names(y), names(x))] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R, and struggling to get `ggplot2` to reliably work. Even simple code snippets that have been reproduced elsewhere are failing on my machine.

This:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
```

Gives me:

> Error in y[setdiff(names(y), names(x))] : 
>   object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Importantly, this was working yesterday. I can't think of anything that changed. Now it's not.

I've reinstalled R, Rstudio and `ggplot2` to no avail. My guess is that there's a versioning problem somewhere, but am not sure.

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE

Here's the output from `sessioninfo()`:

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggrepel_0.5   scales_0.4.0  ggplot2_2.1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] labeling_0.3     colorspace_1.2-6 plyr_1.8.3       tools_3.3.0             
gtable_0.2.0    
[6] Rcpp_0.12.5      grid_3.3.0       munsell_0.4.3
```

Comment: You've done something to your R installation/setup the cause this to happen, but it will be impossible to tell what that might be without at least _some_ information. `sessionInfo()` would at least be a start.

Comment: please don't use `qplot()`. it's deprecated and i spent some productive time nigh eradicating it from the ggplot2 docs.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added the output of sessionInfo() and tested another ggplot command. It worked when I restarted my computer once, and then when I tried again it failed.

Answer (score 9):

I can reproduce this error message if I set an invalid default theme. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw) # improper usage of theme_set, should be theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
```

gives me the error

```
Error in y[setdiff(names(y), names(x))] : 
object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

but

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw()) # have now fixed theme_bw
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
```

works fine.

Comment: This should be checked as the answer. This just happened to me, spent half an hour trying to figure out why my plots weren't working; it's because I did `theme_set(theme_classic)` instead of `theme_set(theme_classic())`

Comment: Agreed. This is a silly user error that is very hard to figure out once it's happened. This answer saved me a lot of time